# JavaScript/jQuery How to do .click function properly?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some buttons generated dynamically based on form inputs selected:

```
$.each(fields, function (i, field) {
  var field_id = $('[name=' + field.name + ']').closest("fieldset").attr('id');
  $("#results").append('<button id="jumpToThisStep" data-id="'+field_id.replace('q','')+'">'+field.value+ ' ' +'</button>');
});
```

}

In my `doc.ready` function I have the following:

```
  $('#jumpToThisStep').click(function() {
    var jump_to = $(this).data('id');
    showStep(jump_to);
  });
```

HTML:

```
<button id="jumpToThisStep" data-id="0"> ... </button>
<button id="jumpToThisStep" data-id="1"> ... </button>
<button id="jumpToThisStep" data-id="2"> ... </button>
```

Upon inspecting the elements they all have the proper `data-id` binding. But the only one that fires is the first one. What is preventing the others from preforming their `.click`?

Comment: You should not be making `jumpToThisStep` the value of `id` on each element. The `id` attribute of any element is supposed to be a unique value from all other element `id`s for the entire page.

Comment: @ajp15243 I know that too.. Such a silly mistake on my part. Just goes to show what happens after 13 hours of intensively starring at code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use [event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) here since your buttons are added dynamically so event delegation will help you to attach the click event to these newly created button:

```
$('#results').on('click', '.jumpToThisStep', function() {
    var jump_to = $(this).data('id');
    showStep(jump_to);
});
```

Also `id` is unique, you need to use class for your button instead.

Comment: Please share details... Why? Don't just feed me, please teach me how you fish. (+1 Thanks this works)

Comment: @feed_me_code He was just complying with your name.

Comment: @0x499602D2 as I wrote that comment.. I thought about my name and irony... Ohh the irony indeed.

Answer (score 1):

HTML DOM `id` must be unique. use `class` instead of.

```
<button class="jumpToThisStep" data-id="0"> ... </button>
<button class="jumpToThisStep" data-id="1"> ... </button>
<button class="jumpToThisStep" data-id="2"> ... </button>
```

If you want to bind event on DOM which you add to document after document ready event, must to use `event delegation`.

```
$('#results').on('click', '.jumpToThisStep',function() {
    var jump_to = $(this).data('id');
    showStep(jump_to);
});
```